# mapbox-gl-js create a circle around a lat/lng?

Tags: mapbox-gl-js

I need to create a circle around a point where a user clicks. How would I do this? Every tutorial shows extracting a circle from a geojson source and not creating one. Need to be able to edit the radius as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Did you try something yourself? Following the mapbox examples you should be able to get an idea of how to build something like that.

You would need to do 3 things:

- Create a source that holds the data
- Create a layer of type "circle" for displaying the data as circles
- On every click of the user, extract the "latitude, longitude" and add a point to your data list. Then display all of those points as a circle on the map.

This is an example of how I would have coded that: https://jsfiddle.net/andi_lo/495t0dx2/

Hope that helps you out

```js
mapboxgl.accessToken = '####';
var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
    container: 'map', // container id
    style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/light-v9', //stylesheet location
    center: [-74.50, 40], // starting position
    zoom: 9 // starting zoom
});

map.on('load', () => {
  const points = turf.featureCollection([]);
 
  // add data source to hold our data we want to display
  map.addSource('circleData', {
    type: 'geojson',
    data: {
      type: 'FeatureCollection',
      features: [],
    },
  });

  // add a layer that displays the data
  map.addLayer({
    id: 'data',
    type: 'circle',
    source: 'circleData',
    paint: {
      'circle-color': '#00b7bf',
      'circle-radius': 8,
      'circle-stroke-width': 1,
      'circle-stroke-color': '#333',
   },
  });

  // on user click, extract the latitude / longitude, update our data source and display it on our map
  map.on('click', (clickEvent) => {
    const lngLat = new Array(clickEvent.lngLat.lng, clickEvent.lngLat.lat);
    points.features.push(turf.point(lngLat));
    map.getSource('circleData').setData(points);
  });
});
```

```css
#map {
  height: 500px;
}
```

```html
<div id="map"></div>
```

Comment: The tricky thing here is that your implementation could work for some, but not for others. In more advanced geospatial scenarios, it may be helpful to use the turf js library found at http://turfjs.org/

With turf you could take advantage of more advanced geographic data structures if you need to trace flight coordinates, or other more advanced use cases. Turf does all the geometric/geospatial algorithms for us already